# Monitoring of disk space on multiple Linux server using expect script

Tags: linux, scripting, monitoring, expect, tcl

I'm trying to write a script using Expect for monitoring multiple servers; the connections will be through ssh using a password.

My basic loop is self failing, I'm not sure whether Expect TCL language accepts or not Linux for loop syntax.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f  
server_list="/tmp/DR.txt"  
for HOST in $(cat $server_list) ; do  
spawn ssh -q $HOST  
expect "assword:"  
send "Abcd@123\r"  
interact  
echo ' '  
echo "====For space utilization details for server $HOST===" >/tmp/space_utilization.log  
Df -kh >> /tmp/space_utilization.log  
echo ' '  
done
```

The file `/tmp/DR.txt` contains a list of 100 server names like the following:

```
hzavks01  
dzavks20  
dzavks03  
uzavks05  
acavks30
```

The error I get is:

```
[root@dzavks20 tmp]# ./expect.sh  
invalid command name "server_list=/tmp/DR"  
    while executing  
"server_list=/tmp/DR"  
    (file "./expect.sh" line 2)
```

Comment: Tcl (and expect) variable assignment looks like `set varname value` -- See the [Tcl tutorial](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html), chapter 4

Comment: Also, the `for` loop is shell syntax, not expect. Also `echo` is not an expect command.

Comment: Please add more details such as how you came up with the ideas and solutions present in this script.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to use expect?  Can you just have a simple bash shell that runs the df command remotely via ssh and collect the information into a single file?

If ssh keys are set up correctly from the invoking server to all of the servers in your configuration file, then you do not need to enter any passwords.  The following loop will collect the df output from all of the servers

```
while read -r h; do
    echo "=== Space utilization for ${h} ==="
    ssh "$h" df -kh
    echo ""
done </tmp/DR.txt >/tmp/space_utilization.log
```

Comment: @muku, you will want to read about the `ssh-keygen` and `ssh-copy-id` commands.

Comment: @Glenm- Thanks for your time!!
I'm going with expect script because i cannot make production severs as sshless and also limitation of installing utility like pssh.

It will be great  help if you could help me with expect..Keep learning!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use ssh private key authentication if you can: once you set it up, you don't need to think about it. Also you don't need to store a password in plain text.

Also, the code is a **lot** more complicated:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f  

set server_list /tmp/DR.txt
set fh_hosts [open $server_list r]

# truncate the log file
set log_file /tmp/space_utilization.log  
close [open $log_file w]

set pass "Abcd@123"
set prompt_re {\$ $}

while {[gets $fh host] != -1} {
    spawn ssh -q $host  
    expect "assword:"  
    send "$pass\r"  
    expect -re $prompt

    set cmd "df -kh"
    send "$cmd\r"
    expect -re "$cmd\r\n(.*)\r\n$prompt"

    log_file $log_file
    send_log "\n"
    send_log "====Space utilization for server $host at [timestamp -format +"%Y-%m-%d %T"]===\n"
    send_log -- $expect_out(1,string)
    send_log "\n\n"
    log_file

    send "exit\r"
    expect eof
}
close $fh_hosts
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! I will check this and will update. I'm having restriction on production server using ssh private key authentication. I need to implement monitoring of production server from non-production server which is my scope.

Comment: Correct fc_host variable few places then executed. Getting below below,
**Error:**  

[root@hzavks20 tmp]# ./S_expect.sh  
spawn ssh -q file4  
send: spawn id exp5 not open  
    while executing  
"send "$pass\r"  "  
    ("while" body line 4)  
    invoked from within  
"while {[gets $fh_hosts] != -1} {  
    spawn ssh -q $fh_hosts  
    expect "assword:"  
    send "$pass\r"  
    expect -re $prompt  
  
    set cmd "df -kh..."  
    (file "./S_expect.sh" line 13)